# Integration of Google Identity One Tap service on Asp net core

Tags: c#, blazor, google-oauth, google-identity

I am creating a Blazor server side with C#
I want the user to use their own Google Account to use my service.
To do this I use the google OAuth, and configured on google side elements for my App.

I have added on my website the 'Google Tap' control which display a popup to login:

```html
         <div id="g_id_onload"
             data-client_id="xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
             data-login_uri="http://localhost:2000/api/v1/AuthCallback"
             data-your_own_param_1_to_login="any_value"
             data-your_own_param_2_to_login="any_value">
        </div>
```

Once the user click on the Google button, his browser is redirected
to a POST to the callback address:
http://localhost:2000/api/v1/AuthCallback

that i can see with network developer with some form encoded data :
[image: callback]

I have added nuget package of google.
But i cannot find anywhere any code sample for the Post handling, I am expecting to see somewhere a specific google object define to match the field: 'credential'

for the moment I am blocked with a controller that i have started: (Xoxo type is just put there to stub some type that i do not identify yet, and which should have a 'credential' string property )

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string CallBack([FromForm] Xoxo googleAuth)//Xoxo is a dummy object to check api i called via postman
    {
        LogRequest(); // displays: | POST /api/v1/AuthCallback HTTP/1.1 
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
        int len = HttpContext.Request.Body.Read(buffer, 0, 1000);
        //string body = new string(buffer);
        /*
        var authenticationResult =  HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        if (authenticationResult.Succeeded)
        {
        }
        */
    }
```

what i am looking for is the code to :

- check the validity of credential data
- How to extract data / where i should obtain the mail of user who logged-in : is it in any chance encoded / encrypted in this credential field ?

Comment: Why not do it like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Thank you, yes I have also seen such code from google, the point is that it speaks about only of the code, and nothing is explained about the actual POST callback request how it is handled by this blazor middleware,

Comment: you want to know how it works?  rather than just make it work?

Comment: i want to understand how it works, and make it work
i do what is written and there is incoherency: by folowing some doc I provide a callback api which is triggered and results in white page of my Blazor web site , maybe this call back is invoked by POST instead of GET ? 
Noting in the docs describes about this POST callback with the form encoded parameters, neither how the credential variables is consumed by which layer of the google net core api

Comment: can you check this doc : https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials#disable-one-tap is it helpful?

Comment: I leave one tap for the moment and fall back to legacy button of new google identity.
Because i am dealing in the context of Blazor server i think there is some issue with the default code due to interation of javascript of google and internal state of blazor server, where the google button disapear after 10 ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

indeed there is a lot of google docs on different places.
the data you obtain from the callback is defined here:
[data desc](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference)

The credential string property you display is defined as:
base64-encoded JSON Web Token (JWT) string.

that you may decode by adding on you blazor server the packages to decode jwt:

[image: packages]

once done you can extract the mail fom the payload like this:

```
//http://localhost:2000/api/v1/AuthCallback
[ApiController]
[Route(ApiConst.V1_PREFIX + "AuthCallback")]
public class AuthCallbackController : MyController
{
    public AuthCallbackController()
    {
        _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string CallBack([FromForm] GoogleSignInFormData data)
    {
        LogRequest(); // displays: | POST /api/v1/AuthCallback HTTP/1.1 
        _log.Debug("g_csrf_token: "+data?.g_csrf_token);
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        JwtSecurityToken decodedValue = handler.ReadJwtToken(data.credential);
        string email = (string)decodedValue.Payload["email"];
        return "checked account: "+email;
    }
}


public class GoogleSignInFormData
{
    public string clientId { get; set; }
    public string credential { get; set; }
    public string g_csrf_token { get; set; }
    public string select_by { get; set; }
}
```

I have then created a YouTube video on Google sign in with Blazor server:
[Google sign in new button with Blazor Server](https://youtu.be/jy3A8GkFIw4)